# run out of stamina during workout

Tags: stamina

I just started going to gym (3 times). This morning at 7AM, I attended the class Move it; it is a 30 minutes work out session. Within 10 minutes, I have lost all my energy and almost throw up so I decided to stop the session today. I woke up around 6AM, ate an apple and a banana before the work out session.

Can I know how can I avoid such situation again and causes of the problem?

Comment: What is "Move it" class? What it includes? Weightlifting or own-weight exercises? Or some other type of activity?

Comment: Also 1 apple and 1 banana before the session is not really good energy source

Comment: @DanilGholtsman Move it does not involve any weightlifting; it is a own weight exercise.

Comment: What do you recommend to eat before early morning own weight workout like this?

Comment: Oh, well, in this case one of the best options would be something like whey protein milkshake because of it suppose to absorb fast in theory. Also there are some supplys as sport energy drink mixes (but careful with that)

Comment: If sport supllyments is not an option - you can try oatmeal + bananas. I also eat some cereals and boiled eggs in this case. But its really hard for me to train early as well, I got more energy at the evening, so, I shifted all my gym sessions to the evening

Comment: How many hours before I eat them? If my intense morning training takes place at 7AM should I eat before 6? I did not throw up today because I did not have anything at all in stomach. If I had some I might have throw up everything.

Comment: normally you should eat 2-3 hours before your exercises, but, omg, maybe even better just stick with those energy drinks in case you got such consequences? I mean if you puke after such workouts.

Answer (score 4):

Training in the morning takes a certain amount of adaptation. Most people just aren't used to getting out of bed and 60 minutes later doing something pretty exhaustive.

I'd suggest you look at two different issues here, 1) the tiredness element, 2) the feeling sick.

1) Did you get enough sleep the night before? Did you go to bed at a reasonable time? Were you dehydrated when you woke up in the morning? (did you drink anything?) Had you slept ok the previous few nights? Any of these things can really throw you off your game, especially first thing in the morning.

2) When you do exercise, your body sees it as a stressor and responds by moving blood supply from the digestive system to the muscles to better supply them with oxygen for the exercise demands. As part of this, it doesn't want un-digested food sitting in the gut, so it tries to purge it (as in, making you throw up). Depending on when you ate the apple and banana, your body probably didn't have enough time to fully digest them before the 7am class.

These two are also probably related. If you're feeling sick, then your not going to want to keep going.

For the feeling sick problem, you could try eating less, you could try sipping an easily digestible protein shake (one of the only times I'd recommend one), you could try forgoing food altogether and just having something like a cup of coffee.

When I trained early morning (7am), I'd get up at 6am and have a black coffee and sometimes a banana, then eat properly afterwards. Any more than that and I'd feel quite badly sick and have a terrible training session. Even with that, it took me a good few weeks to get used to getting up and training that soon afterwards.

Don't be disheartened, training first thing in the morning is tough, but keep at it. Make sure you're getting adequate sleep and you'll get used to it before too long.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Since I did not have anything in stomach I did not throw up. What do you recommend to eat before early morning own workout?

Comment: @forethought It's really no different than eating before a workout at a different time of day. You need to give your body time to digest whatever it is you eat. As I mentioned, I used to have a cup of black coffee and a banana before my morning training sessions, and that did me fine (they were fairly intense, strongman style training sessions, so I learned the hard way that I couldn't eat much beforehand).

Comment: @forethought The other thing to take into account is that if you're not used to training in general and you're pushing yourself out of your comfort zone, then you may well feel a bit sick regardless of whether you eat or not. I've been training for a long time, and I still get occasions after an intense session where I have to let my stomach settle for a while afterwards.